# What can I do to 'burn' a journal?

Tags: journals, etiquette

Several months ago, I sent a paper to a journal. Today, I got back a_single_review_, from one reviewer, with comments from the editor that are a sad summary of that reviewers comments. The reviewer clearly wrote the review in a rush (stream-of-conciousness, mispellings, sentences lacking referent. I'm pissed. Is there a journal-ranking site out there, like 'rate my professor'?

And yes. It was totally rejected. But I would understand that, if I'd gotten 1/3 reviewers, instead of 0/1. And no, the editor provided no useful comments.

Comment: 4 months doesn't seem that long to me, but it really depends on your field. But not knowing the journal's review process (do they send it to three people initially? Or does the editor include themself as a reviewer?) it's hard to say much more.

Comment: This sounds like a rant, not a genuine question.

Comment: Could it be that the reviewer isn't a native speaker?

Comment: It is normal to be angry.   You have worked hard on the paper and expected the same level of care.  Unfortunately, some times, this doesn't happen.  It may be due to the topic area as opposed to the journal.  Indeed, some times it is the editor! he/she may be lazy or too busy.    Move on.

Comment: Publish elsewhere, become respcted then, when they want you - you can turn them down by reminding them....

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If the journal is available in print, a matchbook should do.

Make sure there are not any current burning restrictions in your locale due to drought or otherwise, keep the burning outdoors and away from neighboring structures, and use a suitable non-flammable surround such as a metal firepit or ring of stones. Have a little ceremony, and keep in attendance until the embers are cool. Have a pint if that's your fancy, or whatever sort of morsel you like to treat yourself to.

Hopefully after this time, you've had a bit of time to let emotions taper a little bit and you can refocus yourself to doing what you need to do to submit the work to another journal, either as-is or preferably with some edits that take into account any useful feedback you are able to extract from the review you got. Perhaps solicit some feedback from people in your field that you know personally and trust to be honest so you can improve your chances with your next submission.

Rejection is frustrating but normal. Rejection for bad reasons is more frustrating but just as normal. Hopefully you'll have better success next time around, until then, know you aren't alone and that you will have trouble finding an experienced academic who can't share a similar story.